# Echo framework binding request data to Option[T] monad

Tags: go, monads, unmarshalling, go-echo

Let's say I have a REST API implemented with Golang [Echo](https://echo.labstack.com/) framework. I want to have a way to use optional query parameters in request.

I want to use a Option[T] monad from [samber/mo](https://github.com/samber/mo) library.

For instance, I have a following struct describing two query params:

```golang
type SearchInput struct {
    MinPrice    mo.Option[float64] `query:"minPrice"`
    MaxPrice    mo.Option[float64] `query:"maxPrice"`
    SearchQuery mo.Option[string]  `query:"searchQuery"`
}
```

If i had to bind regular `float64` fields, I would use the `ctx.Bind()` method from Echo. However, Echo has no implemented binders for `Option[T]`. Speaking precisely, Echo manages to bind `Option[float64]` somehow, but produces error trying to bind `Option[string]`.

How can I create a custom binder? Echo documentation gives a small [hint](https://echo.labstack.com/guide/binding/#custom-binding) but does not provide any meaningful examples. Also, I could use `BindUnmarshaller()` interface, but it is still unclear without practical examples in the docs.

I tried to search similar problems mentioned in Echo repository issues/discussions but did not find anything significant.

Comment: I don't know, but please pay attention: Just because someone calls something a "monad" doesn't make it a monad. I doubt that Option[T] from package mo actually _is_ a monad (despite being called monad) and thus it might be impossible to use it like you could use a monad.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work out of the box you need to double-quote the string query param.

```golang
func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    u := "/foo?minPrice=0.99&maxPrice=9.99&searchQuery=\"abc+def\""
    r := httptest.NewRequest("GET", u, nil)
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    c := e.NewContext(r, w)
    var in SearchInput
    if err := c.Bind(&in); err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(in)
}
```

Output:

```
{{true 0.99} {true 9.99} {true abc def}}
```

---

If you want to accept unquoted string you'll need to declare a custom type that contains the option type and have the custom type implement either the `echo.BindUnmarshaler` interface or the `encoding.TextUnmarshaler` interface.

```golang
type OptionString struct {
    mo.Option[string]
}

func (s *OptionString) UnmarshalParam(param string) error {
    s.Option = mo.Some(param)
    return nil
}

type SearchInput struct {
    MinPrice    mo.Option[float64] `query:"minPrice"`
    MaxPrice    mo.Option[float64] `query:"maxPrice"`
    SearchQuery OptionString       `query:"searchQuery"`
}
```

```golang
func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    u := "/foo?minPrice=0.99&maxPrice=9.99&searchQuery=abc+def"
    r := httptest.NewRequest("GET", u, nil)
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    c := e.NewContext(r, w)
    var in SearchInput
    if err := c.Bind(&in); err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(in)
}
```

Output:

```
{{true 0.99} {true 9.99} {{true abc def}}}
```